# Background image won't go all the way to the bottom of page

Tags: css

The background image goes to the bottom of the page until you scroll:

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

body:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.20;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/KWp2vVP.gif');
}
```

Comment: Don't post your code as image. This is something to do with the `<!DOCTYPE>` Make sure you have a valid one.

Comment: Can you please copy paste your code as a text?

Comment: Have to use repeat. 100% height will only fill the visible viewport on page load. Anything below the viewport will not be filled with your background unless you allow it to repeat-y.

Comment: Is there a problem with just adding a background image to the body normally? Take it out of the `body:before` and add it to the `body` with `background-size: cover`

Comment: @user2867288 That wont work because I have to change the opacity of the background image. If I change the opacity of the background in the body it will change the opacity of everything in the body.

Comment: Reopen the question, it is completely clear, and also, there are few solutions.

Comment: @ЩąđεЯօɮɛʀֆօπ, you can do something like this, too: https://jsfiddle.net/xmrvfcqp/2/ point is to set body position to relative...

Answer (score 2):

you may set the image inside html and set an opaque color on top of it in body

```css
html {
   background: url('http://i.imgur.com/KWp2vVP.gif')/* fixed then maybe nothing to worry about :) */;
}
body {
  margin:0;
  min-height:100vh;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
main {
  padding:1em;
  width:800px;
  max-width:100%;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<main><h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>

<ol>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>

<blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

<h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ul>

<pre><code>
#header h1 a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
}
</code></pre>
</main>
```

Or set the opacity to html:before with bg img in absolute position and **sized via coordonates** *(top,left,bottom,right)*.

Body will need to be positionned too to stand on top.

```css
html {
  position:relative;
}
html:before  {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
   background: url('http://i.imgur.com/KWp2vVP.gif');
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  opacity:0.2
}
body {
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  margin:0;
  min-height:100vh;
}
main {
  padding:1em;
  width:800px;
  max-width:100%;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<main><h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>

<ol>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>

<blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

<h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ul>

<pre><code>
#header h1 a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
}
</code></pre>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfectly. I didn't think it was working for a second because of CSS caching. If only I knew how to prevent that X(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `background-size: cover;` in your `body:before`

If it doesn't work, please provide us an working example on jsfiddle or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Move your background image to body and out of body:before. It should work fine.

```
body {
  background-image: url('http:/i.imgur.com/KWp2vVP.gif');
}
```

Comment: That wont work because I have to change the opacity of the background image. If I change the opacity of the background in the body it will change the opacity of everything in the body.